# I want to show banner & interstitial ads in my android Ionic App

Tags: angular, ionic5

I'm getting error under these functions **bannerAd()** & **interstitialAd()** in **home.page.ts** saying

for bannerAd() = *Property 'bannerAd' does not exist on type 'AdserviceService'. Did you mean 'BannerAd'?
ts(2551)*

for interstitialAd() = *Property 'interstitialAd' does not exist on type 'AdserviceService'.ts(2339)*

I'have done all prerequisites for working of GoogleAdMob.

**This is my service file:**

```
import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import {AdMobFree,
        AdMobFreeBannerConfig,
        AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig,
        } from '@ionic-native/admob-free/ngx';
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AdserviceService {
constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    private admobFree: AdMobFree,
    public admob: AdMobFree,
    private appVersion: AppVersion
  ){}

  bannerAd() {
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true,
      id: 'ca-app-pub-9929321504910567/2663167409',
    };
    this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
    this.admobFree.banner.prepare();
  }

  interstitialAd() {
    const interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true,
      id: 'ca-app-pub-9929321504910567/2032612086',
    };
    this.admobFree.interstitial.config(interstitialConfig);
    this.admobFree.interstitial.prepare();
  }
}
```

**This is my home.page.ts**

````
import { Router, NavigationExtras } from '@angular/router';
import { AdserviceService } from 'New folder/src/app/pages/service/adservice.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.page.scss'],
})

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private adService: AdserviceService
  ){}

ngOnInit() {
    this.fetchingBannerAd();
    this.fetchingInterstitialAd();
  }

  fetchingBannerAd() {
    this.adService.bannerAd().subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }

  fetchingInterstitialAd() {
    this.adService.interstitialAd().subscribe((resp) => {
      console.log(resp);
    });
  }
}```
````

Comment: please try check this link "https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/admob"

Comment: @RaviAshara your solution is not working.....If you have any other solution please sare

Answer (score 0):

**In Service file**

````
import {AdMobFree,
        AdMobFreeBannerConfig,
        AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig,
        } from '@ionic-native/admob-free/ngx';
import { AppVersion } from '@ionic-native/app-version/ngx';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AdserviceService {
constructor(
    public platform: Platform,
    private admobFree: AdMobFree,
    private appVersion: AppVersion
  ){}

  bannerAd() {
    const bannerConfig: AdMobFreeBannerConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true,
      id: 'ca-app-pub-9929321504910567/2663167409',
    };
    this.admobFree.banner.config(bannerConfig);
    return this.admobFree.banner.prepare();
  }

  interstitialAd() {
    const interstitialConfig: AdMobFreeInterstitialConfig = {
      isTesting: true,
      autoShow: true,
      id: 'ca-app-pub-9929321504910567/2032612086',
    };
    this.admobFree.interstitial.config(interstitialConfig);
    return this.admobFree.interstitial.prepare();
  }
}```
````